# Chartjs with streaming plugin: update y-range

Tags: range, streaming, chart.js

I use the [Chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) tool with [streaming plugin](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming).

My stream contains time data for x and float values for y.

The y data changes a lot over time, sometimes ~ 10^-3, sometimes 10^-9.

My problem is, that ChartJS renders the plot in respect to the whole data in a dataset, but I want to have the min value of the y-axis to be min(visible data) not min(all data) (and same for y-axis max).

I know that I could reduce the TTL value of the streaming plugin, but I want to keep all data (I also use the zooming plugin for ChartJS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually set `ticks.min` and `ticks.max` using visible data only like this:

```js
onRefresh(chart) {
    var yMin = 0;
    var yMax = 1;
    var xMax = Date.now() - chart.options.plugins.streaming.delay;
    var xMin = xMax - chart.options.plugins.streaming.duration;

    // Your data refresh code
    ...

    // Calculate yMin and yMax based on visible data only
    chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data.forEach(function(point) {
            if (point.x >= xMin && point.x <= xMax) {
                yMin = Math.min(point.y, yMin);
                yMax = Math.max(point.y, yMax);
            }
        });
    });
    chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min =
        Chart.helpers.niceNum(yMin);
    chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max =
        Chart.helpers.niceNum(yMax);
}
```